# What's with this green color ( #004D00 )

Tags: gpu

I've noticed this shade of green a few different times when I experience graphical errors on computers. most recently when I had to disable / re-enable my GPU to fix a error with how videos were being displayed on youtube, and the videos that were loaded were all this green color after the restart.

[image: An example]

I've also noticed this color before the thumbnails on youtube videos load in and once when It took up the whole screen for a second because of some kind of bug.

I think this is some kind of fallback color GPUs use because I've seen it on multiple computers, but I wasn't able to find anything about it searching the hex code.